# Change location of chutzpah.log during tfs build

Tags: chutzpah

I'm trying to diagnose some random failures of qunit tests during our tfs (2013) builds. By turning on tracing, I can get chutzpah (4.0.3) to generate a log file in %TEMP%.

However, our build agents could have multiple instances executing and I'm concerned about multiple runs of Chutzpah writing to the same log file. Is there a configuration option for each instance to write to a different log file?

In addition, is there a way to configure the build to automatically copy the log file to the tfs drop location?

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently a way to do this. Please file a request at the [github page](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah) and I can look into it.

Comment: Already done. [Issue #392](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/issues/392) And thanks!